# mysqlcppconn.dll is missing when MFC connect to mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, dll, mfc

I have set up a MFC application and included the following files

```
#include <afxwin.h>      //MFC core and standard components
#include "resource.h"    //main symbols
#include <afxcmn.h>

//mysql connections
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
```

It has produce a system error telling me that

```
The program can't start because mysqlcppconn.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem
```

I have been set my MFC linker and general in the properties same as the setting of my win32 console application. And also put the mysqlcppconn.dll to the same directory of my project. Please help.

Comment: Try moving the `mysqlcpconn.dll` into the same folder as the executable.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem by moving the dll under C:\Window and then it works